# aframe assets not loading gltf in nuxt.js

Tags: webpack, nuxt.js, assets, aframe, gltf

When I use the [asset management system](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/core/asset-management-system.html#accessing-the-fileloader-and-cache) to load a [.gltf](/questions/tagged/.gltf) model in [nuxt.js](/questions/tagged/nuxt.js), the network tab shows the file was loaded, but the console throws an error:

`core:propertyTypes:warn "#cityModel" asset not found.`

Here is a minimal reproducible example that displays the behaviour:

> Note: (This is in [vue](/questions/tagged/vue) as I don't know how to quickly setup [nuxt](/questions/tagged/nuxt) on codepen,
> but the behaviour is exactly the same)

https://codepen.io/onewaveadrian/pen/gOmrwGY

```js
    <template>
      <div id="app">
        <a-scene>
          <a-assets>
            <a-asset-item
              id="cityModel"
              src="https://cdn.aframe.io/test-models/models/glTF-2.0/virtualcity/VC.gltf"
            ></a-asset-item>
            <a-asset-item
              id="officeclip"
              src="https://media.giphy.com/media/IwAZ6dvvvaTtdI8SD5/giphy.mp4"
            ></a-asset-item>
          </a-assets>
          <a-entity camera look-controls position="0 1.6 0"></a-entity>
          <!-- Load via URL -->
          <a-video
            src="url(https://media.giphy.com/media/IwAZ6dvvvaTtdI8SD5/giphy.mp4)"
            width="16"
            height="9"
            position="0 2 -4"
            scale="0.1 0.1 0.1"
          ></a-video>
          <a-entity gltf-model="url(https://cdn.aframe.io/test-models/models/glTF-2.0/virtualcity/VC.gltf)" scale="0.01 0.01 0.01" position="0 1 -4" />
          <a-text position="-1 2.6 -4" text="value:  URL Loaded!;  color:  #000000"></a-text>
          <!-- Load via Asset Management -->
          <a-video
            src="#officeclip"
            width="16"
            height="9"
            position="2 2 -4"
            scale="0.1 0.1 0.1"
          ></a-video>
          <a-entity gltf-model="#cityModel" scale="0.01 0.01 0.01" position="2 1 -4"></a-entity>
          <a-text position="1 2.6 -4" text="value:  Asset Management Loaded!;  color:  #000000"></a-text>
        </a-scene>
      </div>
    </template>

    <script>
      import * as aframe from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/aframe@1.2.0";
      export default {};
    </script>

    <style></style>
```

My best guess so far is, that this is webpack loader configuration issue, since the `.mp4` loads just fine? If yes, how can I fix it to load via asset manager? And also why does it load with direct URL but not via asset manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how vue rendering works (order-wise), but it seems that by the time when `gltf-model` schema is parsed, the HTML node `#cityModel` really does not exist in the DOM yet.

You could

- modify the `gltf-model` component to check the node in the `init` function, or
- just wait until all is mounted and just add the `gltf-model` via `setAttribute()`

[codepen](https://codepen.io/gftruj/pen/oNZxYEj) with a simple timeout:

```
setTimeout( e => element.setAttribute("gltf-model", "#model")):
```

Comment: This works great when applied in a Vue way using `$ref` within `mounted` lifecycle hook. See [updated codepen](https://codepen.io/onewaveadrian/pen/bGqpqje) for implementation Thanks for the hint.


However I still don't understand why the original example works with the video texture without problems and just the gltf won't load. Maybe filesize is the key difference? Video is coincidentally loaded prior to gltf and thus available when requested by DOM component?

Comment: The asset manager sends the [loaded event](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/core/asset-management-system.html#events) once all `gltf`-files have been loaded. HOWEVER that does **not** include the textures! So if a `gltf`-file requests more textures from the server and thus the model can not be displayed yet it still already counts as loaded once the mesh itself is loaded and thus crashes...

Comment: I don't think it's connected to the asset being loaded. The log `asset not found` is [only present](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/src/core/propertyTypes.js#L84-L97) when a `document.getElementById()` query fails - which happens when there is no HTML node corresponding to the query.